# How to call custom deserializer (Jackson 2.x+) from spring 4+

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to de-serialize the date in a specific format. I have created a custom Object Mapper, registering my deserializer there, 
setting the date format. But Jackson still uses the default deserializer.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean id="outJsonMapper" class = "com.workbrain2.mobility.web.util.CustomObjectMapper">
                        <property name="dateFormat">
                            <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                                <constructor-arg value="${rest.api.date.format}"/>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

My Custom ObjectMapper:

```
public CustomObjectMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    DateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    this.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JacksonKeySerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    this.registerModule(module);
}
```